# Single name for primary and standby database with Autonomous Data Guard on Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle-autonomous-db, dataguard

How do I get one name for the primary and standby database, such that I may connect to the primary site but in case of a disaster, the same name can redirect connections to the DR automatically.

Do we have such as an option in Autonomous Data Guard on Autonomous Database?

Answer (score 1):

On Autonomous Database on Shared Infrastructure, once a user enables cross-region Autonomous Data Guard (ADG), the wallet file's `tnsnames.ora` is updated to contain the hostnames of both the Primary database and the Standby database.

So after enabling ADG and downloading a new database wallet, using the one single wallet, a user should be able to connect to the Primary database as well as the remote Standby database, after a switchover/failover.

Read more about this behaviour in the [Oracle documentation on Autonomous Data Guard](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/autonomous-data-guard-about.html#GUID-6CBD41CF-9AB0-43C4-83D3-725F6BD9512F).

*Ref - I am a product manager on the Oracle Autonomous Database :)*

Answer (score 0):

After having enabled an Autonomous Data Guard for your Autonomous Database on Serverless infrastructure, you need to come up with a single Oracle Net service name for your application.

You can build one manually in your tnsnames.ora.

Assuming you have configured ATP-S with Autonomous Data Guard cross-region between Paris and Marseille and that you use a simple TLS connection from a private subnet (which means that you only need to point to a directory containing just your tnsnames.ora using a $TNS_ADMIN environment variable), your entry might be similar to the following model:

```
<myatp>_tp_ha = 
    (description_list= (failover=on) (load_balance=off) 
        (description= (retry_count=15)(retry_delay=3)
            (address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1521)(host=<ATP-S private endpoint's IP in Paris>))
            (connect_data=(service_name=<service-root-name>_tp.adb.oraclecloud.com))
            (security=(ssl_server_dn_match=no))
        ) 
        (description= (retry_count=15)(retry_delay=3)
            (address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1521)(host=<ATP-S private endpoint's IP in Marseille>))
            (connect_data=(service_name=<service-root-name>_tp.adb.oraclecloud.com))
            (security=(ssl_server_dn_match=no))
        )
    )
```

This should allow your application to connect to whichever end happens to be the primary database (Paris or Marseille).